# Cannot check in a project with SVN in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository, share

I am working in eclipse and I am trying to check in a project to `SVN` repository. I have installed `SVNKit 1.7.10 Impementation`.  It is the latest version as far I know. I select `Team -> Share Project` and then I choose a target folder in the repository. Strangely it is impossible for the sharing/check in to succeed because I receive always the same error message:

```
svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at <workspace_path>
```

I have updated the SVN software and I have looked also at all the relevant answers:

[How can I downgrade the version of an SVN working copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716021/how-can-i-downgrade-the-version-of-an-svn-working-copy)

[Subversion "This client is too old to work with working copy" Help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540847/subversion-this-client-is-too-old-to-work-with-working-copy-help?lq=1)

[Subversion: This client is too old to work with working copy '.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088134/subversion-this-client-is-too-old-to-work-with-working-copy)

[Error updating changes svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483457/error-updating-changes-svn)

Nevertheless it still refuses to work and the message remains the same. I can provide also the information that I have installed additionally `Tortoise SVN`, but when I write the command `svn` in command window it cannot recognize it. How should I update the SVN in Eclipse in order to check in the project successfully? Is it recommendable to unistall some plugin and to reinstall it?

**UPDATE:** The project was initially checked out from SVN repository. I have done it with `Tortoise SVN` because from `Eclipse SVN` there was the same problem, which did not allow me to check it out. I have disconnected it from the original repository and after performing some changes in code I try to check it in again in the old or in another repository, but it fails always with the same mesage:

```
Share project was failed.
svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at <workspace_path>
```

To this time I have only three option after selecting `Team` in Eclipse:

`Apply Patch`, `Share Project`, `Share Projects`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems curious that the Share project fails with an incorrect repository version, because the SVN repository metadata is initialized during that phase.

There are two options that are worth to check

1. Make sure that your project is not already shared on SVN when you try to share it. Either check it out from the repository (if it is already shared) using Eclipse (in this case, Eclipse will now about the SVN properties, so it would not suggest to share  it). If the project is a new project that is not already shared on SVN, manually remove all .svn folders from the project directory (you possibly need to do this outside Eclipse), and then try again..
2. You have found a specific bug in either the SVNKit SVN connector, or your Eclipse tooling. But I unless you have tried everything mentioned in the previous step, I would not recommend trying to report the issue to the developers.

Comment: Thank you for your help. See first my update. I have deleted the SVN folders on the disconnecting. If you mean to delete in the workspace from metadata/plugins the folder org.eclipse.team.core, I have done already done with no positive result.

Comment: No, I only meant the .svn folders in the project, not the .metadata. In this case, you most probably found a bug (have already seen some issues that were fixed relatively quickly).

Answer (score 0):

you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/21327415/1197132 answer. the answer is generic and may be applied for your case.